# Use the XCHG instruction to reorder the integers to 10-8-6-4-2 x86 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, byte, dword

I'm trying to swap element 1 with element 5 and element 2 with element 4, in the dword array using xchg instruction. I'm only asking for guidance to help me get started. I have this so far. I'm trying to use these instructions for the dword array.

mov ax,val1 
xchg ax,val2 
mov val1,ax

```
.data
myArray BYTE 2,4,6,8,10
DArray DWORD 5 DUP(?)
.code
main PROC
mov esi, OFFSET myArray
mov edi, OFFSET DArray
mov ecx, 5

L1:  movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]
mov [edi], eax
inc esi
add edi, 4
call WriteDec
loop L1
mov al, byte ptr [esi]
xchg al, byte ptr [esi]+4
mov byte ptr[esi], al
call WriteDec
mov ah, byte ptr [esi]+1
xchg ah, byte ptr [esi]+3
mov byte ptr [esi]+1, ah
call WriteDec
```

Comment: Why do you have `mov byte ptr[esi], al` and `mov byte ptr [esi]+1, ah`? Also try to be more clear when asking, so we can help you.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm trying to use a 3 line technique of the xchg instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swap in the **byte** array lacks the setting of the `ESI` register.

```
mov esi, OFFSET myArray     <<< Add this
mov al, byte ptr [esi]
xchg al, byte ptr [esi]+4
mov byte ptr[esi], al
call WriteDec               <<< Is this useful ???
mov ah, byte ptr [esi]+1
xchg ah, byte ptr [esi]+3
mov byte ptr [esi]+1, ah
call WriteDec               <<< Is this useful ???
```

> I'm trying to swap element 1 with element 5 and element 2 with element 4, in the **dword** array using xchg instruction.

```
mov  edi, OFFSET DArray
mov  eax, dword ptr [edi]
xchg eax, dword ptr [edi]+16
mov  dword ptr[edi], eax
mov  eax, dword ptr [edi]+4
xchg eax, dword ptr [edi]+12
mov  dword ptr [edi]+4, eax
```

Comment: I see, I've tried that before and it wasn't working and now I see what the problem was. I wasn't using OFFSET DArray before I used the instructions. It's all clear to me now. Also instead of eax I've tried using ebx but it made my project crash. Why could be the reason?

Comment: On many occasions we can not freely modify the `EBX` register. The calling proces may depend on it. On the other hand the `EAX` register is almost always considered available for any purpose.